# How to blacklist, ignorePaths on iframe content using browser-sync

Tags: javascript, node.js, xhtml, browser-sync

I am using browser-sync to develop ui for a site, and the browser-sync snippet is being injected into an iframe on the page, which references a xhtml file from an epub 3.0.
This produces an error because you can't use document.write() on xhtml which is how browser-sync injects it's script into the page.

I've tried using

```
var sync = require('browser-sync');

sync({
    server: {
        baseDir: [
            '.',
            'bower_components' //- Because i'm making a polymer element, so when bower installed, ../path leads into bower_components
        ]
    },
    snippetOptions: { //- I've tried each of the following by themselves also
        blacklist: ['path/to/iframe/file.xhtml'], 
        whitelist: ['index.html'],
        ignorePaths: ['path/to/iframe/file.xhtml']
    }
});
```

But it still injects the snippet into the iframe

I've also tried using browser-sync not in snippet mode (not setting proxy or server in config), but it doesn't reload the page on index.html when I manually place the snippet script into it.

```
sync({
    serveStatic: ['.', 'bower_components']
});
```

With the following at the end of index.html, the only file I want browser-sync to inject.
    //http://HOST:3000/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.2.9.3.js'></script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));//]]>

I made sure HOST:PORT matched the port that browser-sync was using

following the documentation from here
http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-server